# Reformatting data from columns to rows

Tags: r, perl

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
ID  C1 C2
A   S1  1
A   S2  1
A   S3  2
A   S4  2
B   S1  2
B   S2  2
B   S3  2
B   S4  2
C   S1  2
C   S2  2
C   S3  1
C   S4  1
```

And would like to reformat to:

```
ID S1 S2 S3 S4
A 1 1 2 2
B 2 2 2 2
C 2 2 1 1
```

Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in R or Perl?

Comment: Yes I would like to do this in perl. Would you recommend using hash?

Comment: If you're using Perl, why did you add the `r` tag to your question? I would recommend [searching for a similar question](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+columns+to+rows+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and if you can't find a working answer after a few hours of research and coding attempts, post a new question with only the `perl` tag.

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, we can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, ID~C1, value.var='C2')
#   ID S1 S2 S3 S4
# 1  A  1  1  2  2
# 2  B  2  2  2  2
# 3  C  2  2  1  1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(df1, tapply(C2, list(ID, C1), FUN=I))
```

Or

```
xtabs(C2~ID+C1, df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative using `tidyr::spread()`:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, C1, C2)
  ID S1 S2 S3 S4
1  A  1  1  2  2
2  B  2  2  2  2
3  C  2  2  1  1
```